# Slide div under button clicked within a list of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a section tag that contains a div which consists of a list buttons. I have a hidden div within this button div that I want to slide down under the button clicked which pushes down the rest of the content below it. How would i go about this? I have tried using the CSS position : relative but I don't think I'm using it correctly. Here is my HTML code:

```
    <section style="float: left;" id="querySelection">

                    <div id="queryButtons">


                    <input class="btn btn-info net-man" id="zStory11" type="submit"
                        value="Top 10 Market/Operator/Cell ID combinations" />

                    <input class="btn btn-info net-man" id="failuresPerDeviceBtn" type="submit"
                        value="Failures per Device" />

                    <input class="btn btn-info cust-rep supp-eng net-man" id="failuresPerImsiBtn" type="submit"
                        value="Failures per IMSI" />

                    <input class="btn btn-info cust-rep net-man supp-eng" id="st6_CauseCodesPerImsiBtn" type="submit"
                        value="Failure Cause Codes per IMSI" />

                    <input class="btn btn-info supp-eng net-man" id="imsisPerFailureClassBtn" 
                        type="submit" value="IMSI's Per Failure Class"/>

                    <input class="btn btn-info net-man" id="top10ImsiCallFailsTimePeriod" type="submit"
                        value="Top 10 IMSIs with Call Failures" />

                    <div id="queryPanel">

                    </div>
                 </div>

    </section>
```

How would i go about sliding the "queryPanel" div below the button clicked. Here is the JavaScript used when a button is clicked.

```
   if($('#queryPanel').is(':visible')){
       $('#queryPanel').slideToggle("fast");
    }
    else{
        $("#queryPanel").slideToggle("slow");
    }
```

At the moment this slides the "queryPanel" div under the "queryButtons" div which is not the desired result

Comment: you seem to be missing a chunk of code from your html. also can we get the css.

Comment: The section tag at the top was missing

Comment: Right you cant use section like this for a start. Section is not a wrapper. wil still need the CSS

Comment: Edited the question, hopefully it clarifies more. I removed the section tag and still the same result

Comment: It's probably pretty easy to fix, but we need to see some more code and/or a JSfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
$(".net-man").click(function(){
    var elem = $("#queryPanel");
    $("#queryPanel").remove();
    elem.insertAfter($(this));
    $("#queryPanel").hide().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zn31j1bu/)